# Override Template not showing on the Template Style Dropdown

Tags: joomla

I have already made a override on the following location as said in Joomla Documentation:

```
templates\new_vision\html\com_content\category\publications.php
```

So I have linked the Component to the Menu. When goto the Menu to edit the Template Style with the override Template, it doesn't show in the drop-down. Below is the screenshot.

Please advise what am I missing over here.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to assign the template style dropdown with your template name(until you prefer for another template for that menu), by default joomla pick your default template folder if any override found in that it will execute.

Comment: Template Overrides do not appear in the dropdown. These are for Layout Overrides which are nearly the same but a little different ;)